# How can I retrieve an express given a cookie in post body. Express Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, session, cookies, express

Due to issues with CORS, I cannot send cookie information through headers, so instead I need to send cookies within my body post. To accomplish this, when creating a session, I must retrieve the cookie from the created session. Example:

```
// Server Side
var session = express.session({secret: 'mysecret', store: mongoStore});
// I want to do this
var cookie = session.getCookie;
res.send({myCookie: cookie, body: ...});
```

On my client I can then retrieve the cookie from the body. Normally I would just retrieve the cookie set in the response headers -> "Set-Cookie" but for some reason, but browser isn't allowing me access. Thats ok because I can still get information through the response body. Anyway, I need to later send back that cookie after authentication:

```
// Client Side
var data = {
  myCookie: sendBackCookie,
  clientData: data
};
post(data, myUrl);

// Express side
function(req, res) {
  req.cookie;
  // I need to do something like this
  req.session = app.getSession(cookie);
}
```

Short of writing my own session code, I'm really not sure what to do. Is there a library or something I could that can retrieve or set my session from a cookie I retrieved. And can I get a cookie from a session I made?

Comment: Why can't you send cookies with your XHR requests? Just use `xhr.withCredentials = true;` if you have XHR2. Otherwise there are other cross-domain options that let you use cookies.

Comment: Because my origin is null and browsers dunt show you to send cookies when you have no cookies. The point behind my software is to get around Cors issues.